# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError using Jpcap

Tags: java, windows, netbeans-7, winpcap, jpcap

I am using `jpcap` in my java program. I tried everything to get it run but nothing works.

Gives exception: :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\Jpcap.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I am using `netbeans7`, `JDK7`, `Windows 7` all 32 bit

Comment: And where is your `Jpcap.dll`?

Comment: in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin\Jpcap.dll and also in C:\Windows\System32 folder

Comment: Are you sure that `Jpcap.dll` is 32bit too?

Comment: @Mohit check my answer below. Mark it as accepted if it helps. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely sure that your OS, Java and the DLL are all 32-bit, then you may be missing the Windows implementation of libpcap library. Try below steps:

1) Uninstall any previous versions of jpcap

2) Install winPcap and then, run the jpcap installer

3) C:\WINDOWS\system32\Jpcap.dll (check it exists)

4) C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext\jpcap.jar

5) try running your java Program again. Ensure that you have `-Djava.library.path=C:\WINDOWS\system32\Jpcap.dll` in your Java launch command.